# VSCODE file explorer segue arquivo aberto

Tags: visual-studio-code

Alguém sabe como desativar esse comportamento do VSCODE? Toda vez que fecho um arquivo ele pula pro próximo aberto e o file explorer pula pra onde esse arquivo estiver na lista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altere para false a instrução abaixo:

```
"explorer.autoReveal": false
```